# How to install Precise Pangolin as a second OS on a PC with a RAID?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, system-installation, raid

I want to install Ubuntu as a second operating system beside Windows XP SP3.

My main PC has a mainboard based on the nVidia nForce4 architecture with an onboard (mainboard) nVidia RAID controller, 4 disks in a 0+1 configuration.

Is it possible to install on this beast with a normal CD? Will the installer work fine with such hardware?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please add the make and model of your motherboard to your question to help us help you find answers! Thank you!

Comment: This appears to have been a bug in ubiquity (the installer) which it appears was fixed. See this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/90235